# Calculate Days Between Two Dates

Tags: delphi, date, datetime, delphi-7

Please help me find days between two dates.

I have two objects TDBDateEdit date1 and date2.

```
procedure Torder_form.date2Click(Sender: TObject);
var d3: TDateTime;
begin 
    d3:=date2.date - date1.date;
    showmessage(datetostr(d3));
end.
```

I put to `date1 = 07.10.2015`

to `date2 - 15.11.2015`

Result must be: `39`

But program gives me result: `07.02.1900`

---

I found DaysBetween function. and I changed my codes like that

```
procedure Torder_form.date2Click(Sender: TObject);
var d3: TDateTime;
begin 
    d3:=DaysBetween(date2.date,date1.date);
    showmessage(datetostr(d3));
end.
```

But programs says Result: `07.02.1900`

Comment: You're calculating a number (39), then storing the result in a date and so it's displaying as a date (07.02.1900).

Comment: Ask yourself how DateToStr knows you want to interpret the value as a time span or a date?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're trying to store a non-date value (the number of days between two dates) in a `TDateTime` value. Since you don't want a **date**, use a double instead, and interpret it as a double:

```
var
  DaysDiff: Double;
begin
  DaysDiff := Date2.Date - Date1.Date;
  ShowMessage(FloatToStr(DaysDiff));
end;
```

Better yet, use the functions in `DateUtils` to do the work for you. If you need just whole days, use `DaysBetween`:

```
var
  DaysDiff: Integer;
begin
  DaysDiff := DaysBetween(Date2.Date, Date1.Date);
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(DaysDiff));
end;
```

If you need fractional (partial) days, use `DaySpan`:

```
var
  DaysDiff: Double;
begin
  DaysDiff := DaySpan(Date2.Date, Date1.Date);
  ShowMessage(FloatToStr(DaysDiff));
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for everyone I understand my mistake. And problem solved

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in one of my projects. but after a little search in Delphi help, I find out Delphi has a rich set of functions on dates. Anyway you can use from 'DaysBetween' function to solve your problem. My code was something like this:

```
procedure TForm1.btnResultClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  FirstDate, SecondDate: TDateTime;
  format:TFormatSettings;
  intDays: Integer;
begin
  format:= TFormatSettings.Create();
  format.ShortDateFormat :=  'yyyy/mm/dd';
  FirstDate := StrToDate(eFirstDate.Text,format);
  SecondDate := StrToDate(eSecondDate.Text,format);
  intDays:= DaysBetween(FirstDate,SecondDate);
  eFinalDate.Text:= intToStr(intDays);
end;
```